# SQL to query same columns with name and value in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns

```
Id  name    value
1   m1  v1
2   m2  v2
3   m3  v3
4   m4  v4
5   m5  v5

select *
from table
where name = m1 and value = v1  and name = m2 and value = v2
```

But currently this wont return any values .

Can anyone please help how to write the sql to handle the above situation.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you want to do.  Desired results are helpful.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: yes please tell us what are you trying to expect

Comment: It's Imposible that "name" field has a value of m1 and m2 at the same time, at least in this universe. Maybe a quantic state computer...

Answer (score 2):

You need an `OR` Name cannot equal m1 AND m2.  `

Try

```
select * from table where (name=m1 and value=v1) OR (name =m2 and value =v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right...

```
select *
from table
where name in ('m1', 'm2') and value in (v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no row that will meet your search criteria. Should be

`(name = m1 and value = v1) or (name = m2 and value = v2)`